# LibreOffice, Using Constants as query Parameters

Tags: libreoffice

I'm using the VLOOKUP function to move data from one table into another. I need to apply this formula to an entire column, and I need to know how to define certain parameters as variable and some as constant.

Here's my problem:

```
=VLOOKUP($D8,Sheet2.A1:B20,2)
```

becomes, when I drag the corner of the cell across multiple rows,

```
=VLOOKUP($D8,Sheet2.A1:B20,2)
=VLOOKUP($D9,Sheet2.A2:B21,2)
=VLOOKUP($D10,Sheet2.A3:B22,2)
=VLOOKUP($D11,Sheet2.A4:B23,2)
```

And what I need is

```
=VLOOKUP($D8,Sheet2.A1:B20,2)
=VLOOKUP($D9,Sheet2.A1:B20,2)
=VLOOKUP($D10,Sheet2.A1:B20,2)
=VLOOKUP($D11,Sheet2.A1:B20,2)
```

With the first parameter changing and the rest remaining constant. I'm sure there is an easy way to do this, but searching and browsing help topics is returning nothing. I admittedly have zero background in spreadsheets. Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add more `$` signs, like this:

```
=VLOOKUP($D8,Sheet2.$A$1:$B$20,2)
```

https://help.libreoffice.org/Calc/Addresses_and_References,_Absolute_and_Relative